# how to convert the jquery element text() into string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I can not successfully get the string using the jquery text()
I have my HTML

```
 <span>/</span>
            <span onclick="
            var inner_text=$.trim($(this).text());

        if(inner_text=='Send Request'){

        var post_id=<?php echo $blog_id  ;?>;

        var event_date='<?php echo $blog_feeds['valid_date'] ?>';
        var post_text='<?php echo addslashes($blog_feeds['post_text'])  ?>'; //if the string contains ' , then would have error
        var request_text_id='<?php echo $blog_id.'comment_text';?>';


        var request_content=$('#'+request_text_id).val();
        var who_post='<?php echo $blog_feeds['username']  ;?>';


        $.ajax({
        url:'php/join_request.php',
        method:'post',
        data:{request_content:request_content,post_id:post_id,who_post:who_post,event_date:event_date,post_text:post_text},
        success:function(data){

        if(data=='ok'){


            $('<?php echo '#'.$blog_id.'request_w' ?>').html('You have sent '+who_post+' a joining reuqest on this event');
            $('<?php echo '#'.$blog_id.'request_button'; ?>').html('Request Sent');
            $('<?php echo '#'.$blog_id.'request_button'; ?>').css('opacity','0.7');
            $('<?php echo '#'.$blog_id.'request_button'; ?>').css('cursor','initial');
            $('<?php echo '#'.$blog_id.'comment_text';?>').val('');
        }


        }
        })
        }
        "    id="<?php echo $blog_id.'request_button'; ?>" class="j_request_button">



        <?php
        $select_request=mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `join_request` WHERE `post_id`='$blog_id' AND `who_request`='$username'");


        if(mysql_num_rows($select_request)>=1){
        echo '<span style="opacity:0.7;cursor:initial">Request Sent</span>';

    }
        else{

        echo '<span style="cursor:pointer">Send Request</span>';

        }
        ?>
        </span>
```

if I add a alert(inner_text) right before if statement, I can successfully alert "sent request",but I can not alert ok within the if statement

Comment: it IS a string. it just isn't exactly the string you think it is. it probably has a space tab or linebreak in it.

Comment: Is there any whitespace in the HTML? You may need to trim `inner_text` to ignore it.

Comment: seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/BkuSX/

Comment: It's not an extra closing tag. He has two opening tags, he needs two closing tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
var inner_text=$.trim($(this).text());
```

This will remove any surrounding whitespace, which is likely if you have line breaks between your spans.

Comment: Since jQuery is here, i'dd suggest using `$.trim(string)` for browser support. I don't know the current support states for `string.trim()`..

Comment: MDN says it's compatible with IE9. I've updated as suggested.

Comment: If you post your real HTML, we can tell you where the spaces come from.

Comment: yes, i modified it, and any bad influence that I use something mixed like this, php, javascript and html all mix arround, and this would be handy for me to get access the data quickly and easily

Answer (score 0):

Don't put a full script like that in your HTML. Give your span an id, and use jQuery in a separate script tag:

```
<span id="sent_request">sent request</span>
<script>
  $('#sent_request').click(function(){
    var inner_text=$(this).text();
    if(inner_text=='sent request'){
      alert('ok'); //not working
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: how is that relevant ?

Comment: You've also changed the structure of the HTML, he had nested spans.

Comment: @Barmar That's on purpose.

Comment: It's that any influence to my functionality, I do it like this because I can easily get access to the varibles of php